# Draw out of canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I have been developing a program which includes some sort of genetic algorithm. For my program, let's say there is a population of 200 units, and each unit can be in 5 different states. Inititlly, they all start at state 0, and they can randomly jump to states 1 to 4, and influence other units to jump as well. This way, the more units are on state 2, the more units will jump to state 2 and so on. I have these units moving randomly inside my canvas, bouncing off the walls when they hit them.
The one thing I want to do now is visualize the evolution on a chart, and for that I would like to have the canvas with the units jumping states on one side and the chart next to it, dynamically representing the percentage of units in state 0, 1, 2... simultaneously. I will presumably have no problem in coding the chart, however I cannot find a way of displaying it outside the canvas or without altering it. 
Just in case, I am programming in Atom and have mostly used p5 libraries.
Any ideas??

Comment: On a second canvas? Or, perhaps on the one you already have. After clearing, before you draw the initial picture. (both graphs superimposed on 1 canvas) Hard to know what to suggest without knowing why the problem's defeating you.

Comment: Alright I will try to explain myself better. I have my starting code with the command createCanvas(600, 600); and it is inside this canvas where all my units are moving. I want to plot a graph next to it representing the evolution of my units, but I don't know hoy to create an object which will be out of the boundaries (600, 600) of the canvas. I don't know if it is possible to create a second canvas next to my existing one, if there exists some special code either on html or js... Furthermore, this graph need to be updating on each frame. I don't now how to approach this problem.

Comment: Ah-hah, gotcha. Well, it sounds like the thing that would suit me best in your situation is to create a second canvas next to the first one. You'll need to do a little CSS work to get them to align properly - as a result, you're rewarded with simpler drawing of the second graph (simpler since it doesn't need to be +X translated). I'm not familiar with either of the libraries you mention. Whenever I want another canvas, it's a simple matter of `let someVar = document.createElement('canvas');` (continued)

Comment: In fact, if you look at the doc page for `createCanvas`, you may see "Calling createCanvas more than once in a sketch will result in very unpredictable behavior. If you want more than one drawing canvas you could use createGraphics (hidden by default but it can be shown).". So, I suppose that when using P5, you'll draw each graph to it's own canvas, which may either be combined onto a single one or simply resented along-side one another. (@gman has written some fantastic code and articles which are linked on his profile page)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Make a second canvas (Like enhzflep said), but this might be complicated for you, becuase you will not have access to P5.js drawing tools on that second canvas, look at this:

(On your first canvas)

```
fill(255,0,0)
rect(50,50,50,50);
```

To make and draw to a second canvas:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
//deal with positioning, scaling, and other stuff (comment if you need help with that)
...

const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.fillStyle = "rgb(255,0,0)";
c.fillRect(50,50,50,50);
```

(See, lots of effort)

2. Or, you can just use your first canvas, and partition a section off that is dedicated to the graph

```
createCanvas(600 + graphWidth, 600);

//Wherever your bouncing off walls code is
//for the right side of the screen

if(this.x > width - graphWidth){
  bounce();
}

//that leaves you a graphWidth by 600 rectangle for you to draw you graph
```

The second option is much easier to read and will save you some headaches (I would use that).